# Suma de DF en Pandas

Tags: pandas

me gustaría saber como sumar dos data frames en Pandas en los cuales no coinciden todas las etiquetas. Es decir, si la etiqueta coincide en los DF se suman, pero si solo existe en una que añada ese valor únicamente al resultado y no "NaN".

El ejemplo es el siguiente:

DF1

[image: DF1]

DF2

[image: DF2]

si sumo ambos DF el resultado es el siguiente

[image: DF1+DF2]

Como se ve solo suma los Time Spent de los Assignee que coinciden en ambos DF, el resto es NaN. Como se puede hacer para que los NaN sea el valor que hay en unos de los DF?

No se si está claro así.

Muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Voy a poner otro ejemplo más simple por no copiar los datos que has puesto como imagen.

Supongamos que tenemos un par de dataframes como los siguientes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,1,1], index=list("abcdef"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,1], index=list("bcdeg"))
```

Que te muestro uno al lado del otro para que se puedan comparar fácilmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve, comparten algunas entradas del índice (en concreto, b, c, d, e) pero hay entradas que sólo están en `df1` (a, f) y otras que sólo están en `df2` (g) y además no son de la misma longitud.

Si intentas sumarlos así:

```
df1 + df2
```

las entradas que no aparezcan en ambos toman por defecto el valor `NaN` en el df en que no aparecen. Al sumar `NaN` el dato del otro dataframe en que sí aparece, el resultado es `NaN`, ya que `NaN` sumado a cualquier otra cosa da siempre `NaN`. Por eso el resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si en vez de `+` usas el método `.add()` de los dataframes, entonces puedes especificar con qué valor rellenar los datos ausentes. Por defecto sigue siendo `NaN`, pero puedes especificar otro mediante `fill_value`. Si decimos que use 0 como valor de relleno, al sumar éste con el dato del otro dataframe saldrá como resultado el dato del otro, que creo que es lo que querías:

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Bonus. Generalización

La forma más general, para sumar cualquier número de dataframes de este modo, podría consistir en aplicar repetidas veces `.add()` dentro de un bucle. Por ejemplo:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]:
  result = result.add(df, fill_value=0)
```

Lo he testeado y funciona!

## Bonus 2. Usando `+`

Podemos hacer uso del modelo de datos Python, que permite que las clases que tú definas decidan cómo implementar la operación `+`, si implementas en la clase el método especial `__add__()`.

De este modo podría definir una clase `DataFrameSumable` que implemente `__add__()` llamando al método `.add()` de Pandas, con `fill_value=O`. Para no tener que definir el resto de la funcionalidad, uso herencia y heredo de `DataFrame`. Debo tener cuidado de que mi método `__add__()` retorne un `DataFrameSumable` (y no un `DataFrame` normal), para poder aplicar de nuevo `+` al resultado.

Esta sería la definición:

```
class DataFrameSumable(pd.DataFrame):
  def __add__(self, other):
    return DataFrameSumable(self.add(other, fill_value=0))
```

Ahora crearía mis dataframes usando esta clase, en vez de `pd.DataFrame()`, por ejemplo así:

```
df1 = DataFrameSumable([1,1,1,1,1,1], index=list("abcdef"))
df2 = DataFrameSumable([1,1,1,1,1], index=list("bcdeg"))
df3 = DataFrameSumable([1,1,1,1,1], index=list("abcde"))
```

Y resulta que ¡puedo usar `+` para sumar estos objetos y todo sale bien!

```
>>> print(df1 + df2 + df3)
     0
a  2.0
b  3.0
c  3.0
d  3.0
e  3.0
f  1.0
g  1.0
```

¡Magia!

Comment: Muchas gracias.. ahora si

Comment: Te había respondido esto mismo a tu anterior pregunta, antes de que la borraras. Probablemente no llegaste a ver mi respuesta

Comment: te lo aradezco igualmente.. la he borrado porque no parecía que estuviera clara la duda. Muchas gracias de todas formas

Comment: ya que estoy, y perdona el atraco... como harías con tres DFs?

Comment: Supongo que puedes "encadenar" los add: `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).add(df3, fill_value=0)`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: @Gonzalo he extendido la respuesta con cosas nuevas que te sorprenderán. Ah, y si consideras la respuesta válida la puedes marcar como aceptada.